# What can I do for a static class to be reloaded/reinstantiated?

Tags: c#, .net

An application I work with has a static class that loads some configuration from XML files in its constructor.
But when we make changes to one of these XML's, this class is not reloaded (as it should be, since it is static).
What can I do for this static class to be instantiated again, reloading the configuration?
Would I need to restart the IIS server? Are there some other ways?

Comment: You would need to call the method that loads data from the XML file to your static class once again.

Comment: You could have a background process that monitors your XML files and triggers a call to the class if one of the files changes. But, yes, you need to call the class again somehow.

Comment: Maybe it is better to add a method to update data in static class. Every time you want to access XML data, call this method in static class.

Comment: This is why you might want to re-evaluate this. Probably better to use a Singleton pattern with locks and  with data invalidation

Comment: Perhaps you should rethink using a `static` class in the first place

Comment: You can use a file watcher to recognize when the XML file changes and trigger whatever logic is necessary to re-initialize the class when it does https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 0):

Probably better to use a Singleton pattern with locks and  with data invalidation

(typed in here so sorry in any syntax is wrong)

```
public class MySingleton
{

     
    private static MySingleton _instance;
    private static object _lock = new object();

    private static MySingleton 
    {
        // initialize here
    }

    public static MySingleton Instance
    {
        get 
        {
            var singl = _instance;
            if (singl != null)
                return singl;

            lock(_lock)
            {
                if (singl != null)
                    return singl;

                _instance = new MySingleton();
                return _instance;
            }
        }

    }

    public static void Invalidate()
    {
        lock(_lock)
        {
            _instance = null;
        }
    }


    // -- your non-static methods
    public bool CheckSomething(){ return true;  }
}
```

use

```
// thread one
if (MySingleton.Instance.CheckSomething())
    // my code


// thread two
MySingleton.Invalidate();
```